# Laravel file image not show in the production server

Tags: php, laravel, image, file, production

When I run in my local, the image file is shown. But in the production server it is not showing.

URL in my local :

```
http://localhost:8000/files/image/GOT7.jpg
```

URL in my production server :

```
http://myApplication.com/files/image/GOT7.jpg
```

.env in the local :

```
APP_URL=//localhost
```

.env in the production server :

```
APP_URL=https://myApplication.com
```

config/filesystem.php

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => storage_path('/app'),
    ],
],
```

file location in the folder public/files/image/GOT7.jpg

How to solve it?

Comment: so you are getting a 404 error for the images?

Comment: what types of exception you're getting?

Comment: Did you check the image is actually present on your server? Maybe you expect it to be taken into your repository and expect it to be present after a deploy but maybe it's not. Also the disk configuration you show has nothing to do with this problem, since you are not working in `storage`, you work in `public`.

Comment: I get an error message Page not found.

Comment: I have checked on the server, the image file already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna take a guess here and say that it is a symbolic link problem.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

You are using a filesystem named `local` which has its root in `storage_path('/app')`. This is a reference to the `storage` directory in your Laravel project.

This directory by default is not accessible. Nor should it ever be. *Only* your `public` folder should be accessible from the internet (so everything goes through `public/index.php` only).

So a solution that Laravel offers is to place a symlink in your `public` folder to a particular storage path. See the link above.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

This would create a symbolic link for you in `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`. This should now make your files accessible. For more finetuning see the Laravel docs link above.

Comment: where will i execute "php artisan storage:link" ? In my server producion or in my local? Iam new in laravel

Comment: running commands locally will only change local things obviously

Comment: do i have to change the settings in filesystem.php too?

Comment: My project is using laravel version 5.1.46.
Can I use php artisan storage: link?
From several articles that I read, php artisan storage: link is only for laravel at least version 5.3

Comment: Laravel 5.1 is out of service for 2 years now, I suggest you update to a newer version to profit from security patches etc. There are migration guides on the Laravel documentation page.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your time :)